# How to send response from rest webservice

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, rest

I am new to REST webservice. What I was trying that I have a html page with a text box in it. the content of the text box will send using a url. Here is the code-

```
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    function restCall(){            
        var user=$('#name').val();
        var psw=$('#pswd').val();           
        var url="http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-HelloWorld/rest/helloWorldREST/"+user+"?value="+psw+";";
        alert(url);
        $(location).attr('href',url);
    }
</script>
<div style="padding-left: 300px; padding-top: 200px;">
    <input type="text" value="" id="name" /><br><br> 
    <input type="password" value="" id="pswd" /><br><br> 
    <input type="button" value="Show" onclick="restCall()"/>
</div>
</body>
```

Now the java code in servlet is as follows-

```
@Path("/helloWorldREST")
public class HelloWorldREST {

@GET
@Path("/{parameter}")
public Response responseMsg( @PathParam("parameter") String parameter,
        @DefaultValue("Nothing to say") @QueryParam("value") String value) {
    String output = "Hello from: " + parameter + " : " + value;     

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
   }
}
```

This code will give the output as=> Hello from: Subho : Subho

Now I dont want to show this. This msg can be shown in console, But I want to call another webservice or any link from here. I mean let I wrote Facebook in the html page textbox, this page write facebook to the console and fire the www.Facebook.com link and go there. How can I do that. Please help...

Comment: `window.location.href = "www.facebook.com";`

Comment: Why do you need to hit the server _at all_ to meet this requirement? I don't get it. Seems this can be done with some simple Javascript like the comment above or jQuery, which you already seems to know.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but posting this answer with the hope that this answer can be helpful for others.

I think you want to redirect to the specified URL in your web service method. If this is the case then you can use the following Response methods

```
 - Response.temporaryRedirect(URI)
 - Response.seeOther(URI)
```

Here is sample code

```
java.net.URI location = new java.net.URI("www.sometarget.com");
return Response.temporaryRedirect(location).build();
```

There are several types of redirects,

- `301 Moved Permanently` `303 See Other` `307 Temporary Redirect`

[Click Here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4) to get more information.

Hope this would be helpful.